# Prove that $6ab-1$ primes infinite?

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Is there any demonstration that there are an infinite amount of primes of the form $6ab-1$ being $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: How is this any different from trying to prove that there are an infinite number of primes that can be written in the form $6n - 1,$ $n$ an integer?

Comment: There are infinitely many primes of the form $6n - 1$.

Comment: @K.Jiang : something looks like a subtle difference, but cant put my finger on it

Comment: I believe there is no difference. Still, even though I know that there are infinitely many 6n + 1 primes, does that imply that there are infinitely many 6n-1 primes?

Comment: Well, since $n = 1 \times n$, no, there's no difference. But, if you don't allow $a$ or $b$ to be $1$, I don't think it's an immediate corollary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is a special case of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), which states that the arithmetic progression $b, a+b, 2a+b, …$ contains an infinite number of primes except when $a$ and $b$ have a common factor larger than 1.

For your question we take $a=6, b=5$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have knowledge of this theorem.